# Shapefile for Petrol Fueling stations across Europe

Tags: geospatial, europe, csv, scraping

I'm looking for petrol stations across Europe either in a shapefile format, coordinate data as .csv or addresses from a webpage which I can scrape.

I have had a look and couldn't find anything that covers all of europe

Comment: I would suggest use OSM Data. Tag: `amenity=fuel` (see: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel). You can create request through Overpas, like https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1fCS